# Postgres: Populate a JSON field with an array of values from a subquery

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm trying to populate a new JSON field with existing data and could use some help getting the field properly formatted. I have a subquery returning a list of values intended to be an array in the JSON property. The subquery returns the right results but I can't quite get the JSON array populated properly.

My query is essentially this:

```
UPDATE foos SET json_property =  
cast(
  '{"bar_ids":' || 
  (select json_agg(x) from (select id from bars) x) || 
  '}'
as json);
```

What I want to store is this:

```
{"bar_ids":[1,2,3,4]}
```

but what I currently get is this:

```
{"bar_ids":[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4}]}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that one subquery is needless:

```
UPDATE foos SET json_property =  
CAST(
  '{"bar_ids":' || 
  (SELECT JSON_AGG(x.id) FROM bars x) || 
  '}'
AS json);
```

Comment: Ah, yeah, you're right.  That nested subquery was the closest working thing I had after tossing stuff against the wall for a while. I yanked that out in my real query and it's working like a charm now!